# InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made - while building an docker image to install requests component using PIP

Tags: python, image, docker, pip

InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made - while building an docker image to install requests component using PIP

**cmd**
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org \
      requests \

**Error:**
Collecting requests
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:849: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py:849: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings